How can I make a Shader Node setup to replicate Atomic Force Microscope like images?
I have models in Blender that look like "A" in the below image.
How can I make a Shader setup that produced images like "B" or "C" when rendered, sort of a blurry gray-scale? I am not even sure where to start.


I can't answer what to use -- but hey, search on "blur".  Or if you're OK with your whole image looking like that, defocus the camera.

Thanks, that sounds like a good place to start.

If you find an answer, please answer your own question.  That'll help the next person.

https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/158013/recreate-electron-microscope-material https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/160244/how-to-recreate-microscopic-diatom-glass-material https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/23571/what-is-this-kind-of-material/23592#23592 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/291999/cant-seem-to-properly-replicate-the-scanning-electron-microscope-appearance

Shaders are generally inadequate to produce blurry shapes alone, that is more the work for post processing With the above links you can easily combine those shaders with some post processing blur to achieve that.

I managed to get something fairly decent like this. Mainly just fiddling with the AO and normal, repeatedly blurring and blending with different Add/Sub blend modes like Overlay, LinearLight etc. I also used a mask to add back in the blurred atom to give it a bit of variation across the image. Its pretty simple really, I think it just takes experimentation to get the exact look dialed in.

Compositor Node Group:



Beautiful! Thank you very much. I up voted this, but I don't have enough reputation for it to show yet. :)

Sounds good, glad to be of help!

I changed the depth of field on the camera to something real small to blur it. I also added a lighter material to the edges to more resemble image "C". I'm still trying to get a strong shadow under like image "C" and "D" with an elongated plane I can darken manually. 
